# React Testing Library vs JsDom

Tags: react-testing-library, jsdom

I'm currently writing a test that checks for a simple input component:

```
it("Renders TextInput Component with correct display value", ()=>{
  const textInput = screen.getByRole("textbox");
})
```

If I wanted to check the value of the text input, should I be checking the attribute or using RTL's screen method (**is there a preferred way of doing this?**)

```
  expect(screen.getByDisplayValue(defaultProps.value));
  expect(textInput).toHaveAttribute('name', defaultProps.name);
```

I would like to start using more of RTL but I'm finding some attributes I pass down are harder to check like the ones below.

```
expect(textInput).toHaveAttribute('placeholder', defaultProps.label);
expect(textInput).toHaveAttribute('type',  defaultProps.type);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, `screen` is the preferred way for sure. Read [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library/&ved=2ahUKEwij6_DO7rHzAhUiRkEAHbTWCkEQFnoECAcQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2rrKhTGLkRUBmDxE4whUDs) article for more info on that and more tips.

On your question about how to check the value of an input fields, you can do it like this:

```
it("Renders TextInput Component with correct display value", ()=>{
  expect(screen.getByDisplayValue('my text')).toBeInTheDocument().
})
```

This will attempt to find an input with a value of "my text", just like a real user would. If it does find it then it's deemed a pass.